# poupup window in javascript and displaying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

I need a popup window with login name, password and submit button. I have created a popup window as shown below with javascript. I am able to print alert, but textfiled and submit button doesn't display in the popup window.

```
loginQB = function(){
    window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'width=640,height=580,resizeable,scrollbars');
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').outerHTML=document.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
    alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML)

}
```

html code:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<form:form method="POST" action="/asi/mappings" onsubmit="loginQB(); return false;">
```

**UPDATE**

```
   var win = window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'width=640,height=580,resizeable,scrollbars');
        win.document.write('<form:form id="qblogin" method="POST" action="/asi/mappings">');
        win.document.write('<br>Sign in with mycompany Account or <a href="www.mycompany.com">CreateOne');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="text" name="userName">');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="password" name="password">');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="submit" value="Submit">');
        win.document.write('</form>');
```

I am getting  Unterminated <form:form tag error. Using spring form tag library as shown above in the html code.

Comment: Why not use a jQuery Dialog instead of a popup?

Comment: `document.write()` doesn't do what you think, it just wipes out everything from the page, only what is left is the input it has written. And this happens on the main page, not in pop-up.

Comment: Your html is broken. `</br>` is not a valid tag. `<br>` is a singleton/solo tag. It should only ever be `<br>`, or `<br />`(xhtml), and why are you trying to use a namespace on html? `<form:form` is not valid html either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a variable to access the window

```
var win = window.open('url', 'popup', 'width=640,height=580,resizeable,scrollbars');
win.document.write('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
```

I'm not sure you want to login like this, it's much more common to use a modal window within the page.

Comment: it works, updated my question above, having form submission issue in popup window.

Answer (score 1):

You are not terminating your <a href> statement.  After CreateOne should be </a>

Comment: thanks, updated code now. it worked. but form action with custom taglib doesnt take action.